# How to send an Outlook (2010) invitation for an event without including myself?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

The partners at my firm would like to be able to send an invitation to multiple employees so that they know to go to Client ABC on Tuesday, but to not have the appointment show up on the partner's calendar, as they will not be going to the client with the employees.

What is the best way to do this without using delegates or having the partner manually edit each employees' calendar directly?